# No provider for smtp

Tags: tomcat, smtp, jakarta-mail, alfresco

I'm running Alfresco v3.4.0E on Tomcat v.6.0.32. Everything works fine except for sending emails through an outbound SMTP server. This is the relevant part of the stack trace I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for smtp 
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:418)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:341)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:356)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345)
    at org.alfresco.repo.action.executer.MailActionExecuter.executeImpl(MailActionExecuter.java:439)
    ... 144 more
Caused by: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for smtp 
    at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:455)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:650)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:631)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.getTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:433)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:387)
    ... 148 more
```

I already made sure that both mail.jar and activation.jar are included in the classpath:

```
[root tomcat]$ ll webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/ | grep mail.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alfresco alfresco   356519 Jan 17 20:38 mail.jar
[root tomcat]$ ll webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/ | grep activation.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alfresco alfresco    55932 Jan 17 20:38 activation.jar
```

Here's an excerpt from my alfresco-global.properties:

```
# Outbound SMTP -- sending emails from Alfresco to the outside world
mail.from.default=noreply@domain.local
mail.port=25 
mail.protocol=smtp 
mail.encoding=UTF-8
mail.header=
mail.smtp.auth=false
mail.smtp.timeout=30000
mail.host=smtp.domain.local
```

I already succeeded sending an email using that very same SMTP server via `telnet` from the Alfresco server.

What am I missing?

---

**UPDATE**

It turned out (thanks, [zaphgod](http://twitter.com/#!/zaphgod)!) that it was all caused by some configuration problems: commenting out some properties solved the issue:

```
# Outbound SMTP -- sending emails from Alfresco to the outside world
mail.from.default=noreply@domain.local
#mail.port=25 
#mail.protocol=smtp 
mail.encoding=UTF-8
#mail.header=
#mail.smtp.auth=false
#mail.smtp.timeout=30000
mail.host=smtp.domain.local
```

Now the question is, why this behavior? I'm pretty sure the properties I used first are with the default values..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is, that the error was caused by a trailing space character in the line mail.protocol=smtp

At least in your posted config and the stack trace a space is present.

Comment: Thanks Florian, I can't check right now but I bet you're absolutely right. I'll let you know as soon as I can double check.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope you did the following:
[Outbound email configuration](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Outbound_E-mail_Configuration)

Comment: Yep, I updated the original question with my outbound email config

Answer (score 0):

Could the mail or activation jar be corrupt? The error you've got does look like you don't have one of the two, so if you think they're there then one of them being incorrect/corrupt looks like the next most likely explanation

Try unzipping them (jars are zip files with metadata), and also try using something like md5sum to ensure they're the one you expected.

Comment: MD5 tell me that the jar files I'm using are already known to the internet, though not particularly popular:
`[tomcat]$ md5sum webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/mail.jar 
0bacd591fbd2ce1a5e0d0062be15ff8e  webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/mail.jar
[tomcat]$ md5sum webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/activation.jar 
d5dd655f6056a72116f6a0666745a386  webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/activation.jar`

Comment: I have:
0bacd591fbd2ce1a5e0d0062be15ff8e  mail.jar
3109d42266e2b4d7c94fabcc63346504  activation-1.1.jar
Have you checked to see if you have any different copies of those jars elsewhere in your tomcat install (eg in common or shared)?

Comment: Yep, I checked the content of each and every jar in the CLASSPATH, just to avoid misnamed JARs. Only the JARs contained in the webapp are providing javamail classes/providers configuration. Thanks for your support, BTW.

Comment: You could try this trick for identifying where the javax.mail classes come from: http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006 - ensure it comes from the jar you expect